# can I make an extra disk?

Tags: windows-7, linux

everyone.
I'm trying(this time on windows) to download (or extract to, anyway) linux to the c drive. the thing is, I need to create a disk. how can I do this?
I'm planning to extract my ISO file to it. If there is a beter way to dualboot, please tell me. (on linux, I don't get the option to dualboot. only replace windows, which I don't want to do.).

Comment: Which distro of linux are you attempting to install? Many will set up dual booting if it detects windows is present.

Answer (score 3):

Extracting the ISO to the root of your C: drive will not allow you to run Linux.

You will need to make sure you have a free partition in which to install Linux.  If you don't, you need to shrink your existing ones, or reinstall Windows from scratch on a smaller one.  [This](http://www.petri.co.il/shrink-system-partition-in-windows-7.htm) tells you how to shink a volume to make room if needed.

Then you need to boot off the ISO and install Linux on the unused partition.

If the ISO cannot setup the bootloader, you can try adding a Linux boot option to the Windows 7 bootloader - look [here](http://blog.famzah.net/2011/11/12/boot-linux-using-windows-7-boot-loader/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to install linux from within windows in order to boot it, you are going to need something such as wubi.

Alternatively you can partition a drive and use a customer installer to install it on the partitioned drive.

Aside from that you will need to still partition a drive to dual boot, and burn it either to a  disc or mount it on a flash drive to install it from outside of windows.